# jQuery fadeTo effect applied to <tr>

Tags: jquery, html, master-pages

I want to add the `fadeTo` effect to a `<tr>` tag using jQuery. This should be possible, right? Here's my code:

```
if ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("tr[id$='_trPendingRequest_Manager']").fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    });
}
```

For whatever reason, the effect is not happening.

I decided to do a bit more testing and added a paragraph tag directly above the table containing this `<tr>`, and I was able to successfully apply the `fadeTo` effect to the paragraph tag. So, this leads me to think that one cannot apply the `fadeTo` effect to `<tr>` tags.

Anyone have a nugget of wisdom they'd not mind sharing with me as to why I can't get this to work?

**EDIT:** Here's the html of the `<table>` with the `<tr`> which I am trying to apply the effect to.

```
<table>
  <tr id="trPendingRequest_Manager" runat="server" style="display: none;" valign="middle">
    <td valign="middle">
      <asp:Image id="imgExc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Mail_24x24.png" />
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="middle">
      <asp:HyperLink ID="hypPendingRequest" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/MyManagedRequests.aspx" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="Black">You have <asp:Label ID="lblRequestsNum" runat="server"></asp:Label>request(s) pending your action
       </asp:HyperLink>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>... Removing the rest for brevity ... </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe you could post some of your html? Copy pasting your code example above and setting up a simple table did produce the desired effect, so maybe there's something else to it all.

Comment: It looks like there may be a conflict with something else, since others are able to get it to work. I'm actually doing this within a masterpage (ASP.NET), and the tr in question is initially not visible. I actually set the display attribute of the tr to "inline" during the masterpage's Page_Load event and only if certain conditions are met. I'll append the html for this as well.

Comment: you need to "SHOW" tr before fading it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working perfectly okay. If this is unique ID then you don't even need to specify tr or matching selector, simply this will do the work:

```
$(document).ready(){function(){
    $("#_trPendingRequestManager").fadeTo('slow','0.33');
});
```

EDIT:-

As I was suspecting the id comes from runat="server" item. You can use this to speed up things.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%=trPendingRequestManager.ClientID %>").fadeTo('slow','0.33');
});
```

I think starting _ was making it behave funny. For more on speeding up with using **ClientID** property read [this](http://encosia.com/2009/06/09/11-keystrokes-that-made-my-jquery-selector-run-10x-faster/) post by Dave.

Also remove **"display:none"** this is the culprit!!!

just chain it to put opacity to 0 if you don't want to remove **display:none**

```
$("#<%=trPendingRequestManager.ClientID %>")
 .css('opacity','0').show() //make transparent and show
 .fadeTo('slow','0.33')
```

I found this [here](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/05/14/patch-jquery-fadeto.html)

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - I try not to embed my scripts in my markup. I like to keep it in it's on .js file (ie - non-obtrusive JavaScript), which is why I am not selecting upon the ClientID of the tag. Though I think you're correct about the display:none attribute - it is likely the problem. I'll do some more testing on it here soon to see if I can't nail it down.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's been my experience that tr elements can't be manipulated normally.  For example, you can add a background color to tr elements (for zebra striping, say) but if you want a line between each tr "row" then you have to add the css border to the td elements under it or it won't seem to have any effect.

My guess is that this is something similar.  You might have to try executing fadeTo on each child td element of the tr element in question... dunno, I admit I haven't tested anything.

Comment: Yeah, I'd thought about trying to apply it on the td tags. Guess I'll give it a try.

Comment: I hate it when the plot thickens, because it usually means I have to provide more code! :)